# Find and Replace XML tag in np++ to specific details

Tags: notepad++, xml

I have a XML file with following data

```
<Shipment>
 <Shipper>
  <Name>Clothes</Name>
  <Address1>Apparel Street</Address1>
  <Country>GB</Country>
 </Shipper>
 <Shopper>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <Address1>Street 1</Address1>
  <Country>IE</Country>
 </Shopper>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
<Shipper>
  <Name>Clothes</Name>
  <Address1>Apparel Street</Address1>
  <Country>GB</Country>
 </Shipper>
 <Shopper>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
  <Address1>Street 9</Address1>
  <Country>US</Country>
 </Shopper>
</Shipment>
```

I want to change only the Shopper addresses to specific one, like below

```
<Shipment>
<Shipper>
  <Name>Clothes</Name>
  <Address1>Apparel Street</Address1>
  <Country>GB</Country>
 </Shipper>
 <Shopper>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <Address1>Wonderland</Address1>
  <Country>CA</Country>
 </Shopper>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
<Shipper>
  <Name>Clothes</Name>
  <Address1>Apparel Street</Address1>
  <Country>GB</Country>
 </Shipper>
 <Shopper>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
  <Address1>Wonderland</Address1>
  <Country>CA</Country>
 </Shopper>
</Shipment>
```

Let me know if there is any easy way to resolve this using Find and replace option in Notepad++

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<Shopper>(?:(?!</Shopper>)[\s\S])+?<Address1>).+?(</Address1>[\s\S]+?<Country>).+?(</Country>)`
- Replace with: `$1Wonderland$2CA$3`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(                               # group 1
  <Shopper>                       # open tag
  (?:(?!</Shopper>)[\s\S])+?      # 1 or more any character, not greedy, and never encountered "</Shopper>"
  <Address1>                      # open tag
)                               # end group 1
.+?                             # 1 or more any character but ewline, not greedy
(                               # group 2
  </Address1>                     # close tag
  [\s\S]+?                        # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  <Country>                       # open tag
)                               # end group 2
.+?                             # 1 or more any character but newline
(</Country>)                    # group 3, end tag
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1                  # content of group 1
Wonderland          # literally
$2                  # content of group 2
CA                  # literally
$3                  # content of group 3
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]